# Many to Many Delete using Id in pivot Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

My Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{

public function transaction(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Transaction', 'product_transaction', 'product_id', 'transaction_id')
            ->withPivot('price', 'qty', 'discount_amt', 'product_total')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

My Transaction Model

```
class Transaction extends Model
{

    public function products(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_transaction', 'transaction_id', 'product_id')
            ->withPivot('price', 'qty', 'discount_amt', 'product_total')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

My Code to delete using product_id

```
public function deleteProducts( $transId, $productId ){

    $trans = Transaction::find( $transId);
    $trans->products()->detach( $productId );
}
```

It does the job of detaching...
The problem is (see photo) I have a duplicate transaction_id and product_id with different quantity. If use my detach it deletes both. I'm thinking to use the pivot id. How to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem using

```
$trans = Transaction::find( $transId);
$trans->products()->newPivotStatementForId( $productId )->where('id', $pivotId)->delete();
```

Thanks to this site https://www.drukhost.com/2015/05/conditionally-deleting-rows-from-pivot-tables-many-to-many-laravel/